# Seam LDAP, update user details

Tags: ldap, seam

I am trying to update user details like firstName, lastName, emailAddress especially using Seam's IdentityManager API bit do not see any method for updating the LDAP. 
Is there a reason for not providing LDAP update method and if so what is the best way to update the details.

Versions used:
Seam-2-1.2
JBoss-4.2.3
openLDAP

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seam until now does not have the facility to update LDAP on its own. In the past, I have used [Spring LDAP](http://www.springsource.org/ldap) or [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/) to achieve that in conjunction with my Seam project. Spring LDAP is very simple to integrate.

Comment: Thank you. Will try spring LDAP.